# html to pdf conversion in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, wkhtmltopdf

I am using laravel 4 and having problem with html to pdf conversion.

I have a method download, when this method is called based upon the parameter passed i call some other methods(e.g download1() method). This method(download1() method) returns the View::make('temp'). 
Now i want to convert this into pdf and show a download prompt.

I tried using several library but not able to convert it into pdf.
Please if anyone have used it before help me.

FYI i am using ubuntu box .

Thanks in advance.
Nikhil

Comment: Using Non latin characters? ( Arabic, Greek, Chinese e.t.c.) ?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this package, you gonna like it.
https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck hard with this one as well. My HTML views are full of Non Latin characters (Greek) characters, and I had many many problems with dompdf solutions with encoding and CSS rules. So I tried this one [wkhtml2pdf](https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf) and just worked out of the box! Not even one problem. I don't know if its really the best, its sure is in my case though :-)

There is an interesting discussion about this (PDF in laravel) in linkein as well. Take a look here ["What is the Best HTML to PDF converter for Laravel 4"](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Which-is-best-Html-PDF-4419933.S.232493367?qid=af2dc883-789f-4775-ba39-26e9fcaac28c&goback=.gmp_4419933)

Comment: I am in ubuntu box, What driver type should i use ??

Comment: It depends! I am using the 64 bit but I know that I have this version. Run uname -a to see this info. If you see something like "x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" you have 64bit.

Comment: I am using the command line version of Wkhtmltopdf, running the command through system PHP function ..
Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: This package integrates wkhtml2pdf nicely with Laravel: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf successfully ... can recommend ...

Comment: I'm using it too. But, if you ever need to use CSS3 with it: JUST DON'T! Too painful!